# C# Regex needs additional characters

Tags: c#

my current string regex is working but I wanted to add `<?php` and `<?PHP`. Here is the code:

```
 @"\b(public|private)\b"

 string Keywords = @"\b(public|private)\b";
```

This is how you can do a div

```
 @"<\s*div[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/div\s*>";
```

How can I add `<?php` and `<?PHP` in the same regex?

Answer (score 0):

> To specify a set of acceptable characters in your pattern, you can either build a character class yourself or use a predefined one. A character class lets you represent a bunch of characters as a single item in a regular expression. You can build your own character class by enclosing the acceptable characters in square brackets.

Read [Using Regular Expressions with PHP](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php) for more details and learn how to use `php` in `regex`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php` is not a word so you cannot use `\b` to match it

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(public|private)\b|<\?php", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match("public");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
match = regex.Match("<?php");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```